# Opening Explorer to a specific file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I've looked at some related questions, and there exist ways of opening `explorer.exe` to a specific file, such that it is selected in the Explorer window. The command line goes something like this:

`explorer.exe /select,"C:\Temp\Myfile.png"`

I ran that command in the command prompt directly to verify that it works, and it does. However, I cannot get it to run in Node in a good way. Some things I've tried:

```
const expl = exec('cmd.exe', ["explorer.exe", `/select,"${root}\\${filename}\"`]);
const expl = spawn('cmd.exe', ["explorer.exe", `/select,"${root}\\${filename}\"`]);
const expl = exec('cmd.exe', [`explorer.exe /select,"${root}\\${filename}\"`]);
```

...and some other variations. I didn't / don't really know what I am doing.

I ended up writing a truly **ugly** solution:

```
function openExplorerSelected(filename){

  let batfile = `explorer.exe /select,\"${root}\\${filename}\"`;
  fs.writeFile("tmp.bat", batfile, function(err){
    if( err ) console.warn(err);
    else {
      const expl = spawn('cmd.exe', ["/c", "tmp.bat"]);

    }
  })
}
```

It works, but ew.

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but it has to be launched as a shell in this case. Both of these work for me:

```js
spawn('explorer.exe', [`/select,"${path}"`], {shell: true})
```

```js
exec(`explorer.exe /select,"${path}"`);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running explorer.exe as the executable, instead of cmd.exe?

```
const expl = exec('explorer.exe', [`/select,"${root}\\${filename}\"`]);
```

Comment: This opens explorer but not to the right path (to say nothing of the selected file).